# Corrected -Different sizes of data for train_test_split

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, machine-learning, training-data

I have input variable X in shape (500, 32) and output variable y in shape (422, 750, 3). I need to train a machine learning model with these variables. When I use train_test_split like this;

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=123)
```

I immediately get

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [500, 422]

as expected. I know training and testing samples must be in same size and I'm wondering if there is any method to deal with it? Thank you.

Edit:I understood that in order to train my machine learning model, my data should satisfy X.shape[0] == Y.shape[0], this solves the whole question and shows me I was on the wrong path.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, you don't have the output y for some of your observations. Right? So, you may use some techniques from semi-supervised learning

Comment: Well in fact my X and y values are the pixel arrays of two different images. @NimaS

Comment: Why do you want to split two pixels like this? `train_test_split` requires `X.shape[0] == Y.shape[0]`

Comment: This is the way I know how to split data. If you have an idea that could better fit my situation, I'd like to hear @Frightera

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the first dimension of X and Y may be batch size, right?
I did a little test on this train_test_split method,

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection as mod

X = np.random.randn(500,422)
Y = np.random.randn(500,750,3)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = mod.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25,random_state=123)

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
```

Then I got results:
(375, 422) (375, 750, 3)

Maybe you should align your X to (422, 32) I guess.

Comment: Well how am I suppose to do that? Both X and y are pixel variables of two different images. @lunacancer

Comment: So I guess you have two sets of pictures, each pics in X is a greyscale of (500, 32, 1), and each pics in y is a RGB of (422, 750, 3)? Well, when using a CNN network or something like that, I always feed it with a 4-dimension tensor, with first dimension as batch size and last 3 dimensions as pixels.

Comment: Oh @lunacancer you may be right, unfortunately I'm not allowed to use any deep learning techniques.